# Scheme Standard Deviation

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to get a function that returns the standard deviation of a single list and my code runs great, but I want to learn how to use map, apply and filter to apply in this code. So far I have use apply on the average function, but I can't get my head around into using them in the rest of the code

```
(define (average li)
  (/ (apply + li) (length li)))

(define (summation li avg)
  (if (null? li)
    0
    (+  
       (* (- (car li) avg) 
          (- (car li) avg))
    (summation (cdr li) avg))))

(define (sd li)
    (sqrt
        (/  
          (summation li (average li))
          (- (length li) 1))))
```

I have a feeling that map can be use in the summation function, yet thing it will make a big mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express `summation` using [`foldl`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29)

```
(define (summation li avg)
  (foldl (lambda (x acc)
           (+ acc
              (expt (- x avg)
                    2)))
         0
         li))
```

While these procedures you supply here seem simple, you should be considering the consequences of their implementation. For example, I'm sure you could write your own `length` function

```
(define (length li)
  (if (null? li)
      0
      (+ 1 (length (cdr li)))))
```

You use `(apply + li)` to calculate a your input list's sum, but I'm sure you realize that's a clever replacement for our simple recursive solution

```
(define (sum li)
  (if (null? li)
      0
      (+ (car li)
         (sum (cdr li)))))
```

Given `sum` and `length`, we implement `average`

```
(define (average li)
  (/ (sum li)
     (length li)))
```

Do you see the problem here? `sum` and `length` both iterate through the input list. Then we go on to write `sd`...

```
(define (sd li)
  (sqrt (/ (summation li
                      (average li))
           (- (length li) 
              1))))
```

Do you see how the problem has worsened? We know `average` already steps through the input list `li` twice, `summation` steps through it *again*, and notice there's *another* call to `length` – we've iterated thru `li` **4** times before `sd` can return its result

Let's rewind a little bit. Looking at `average`, wouldn't it be nice if there was some way we could sum the elements of `li` *and* count them simultaneously? Well we can!

```
(define (average li (return /))
  (if (null? li)
      (return 0 0)
      (average (cdr li)
               (lambda (sum count)
                 (return (+ sum (car li))
                         (+ count 1))))))


(average '(1))     ;; 1
(average '(1 2))   ;; 1 1/2
(average '(1 2 3)) ;; 2
(average '())      ;; Error: division by zero
```

Using this technique, you can perform transformations of virtually any complexity. Writing `sd` using this style is left as an exercise for the reader.